# Discord Webhook Linux Bash - How to pass content of file as string argument

Tags: json, linux, bash, discord, webhooks

I'm trying to set up a Discord webhook that posts info about my backup processes on my server. Specifically the output of an rsync operation (about 15 lines of summary) as an embed webhook.

I decided to use Discord.sh https://chaoticweg.cc/discord.sh/

This expects a string format for the embed description of "line one\nnew line two\nthird line"

Since the output of an rsynclog stretches over multiple lines I used a script with jq to convert it to this format. The input was:

```
Number of files: 101 (reg: 100, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 100
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 5,247
Total bytes received: 1,916

sent 5,247 bytes  received 1,916 bytes  2,865.20 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

The output

```
"\nNumber of files: 101 (reg: 100, dir: 1)\nNumber of created files: 0\nNumber of deleted files: 0\nNumber of regular files transferred: 100\nTotal file size: 0 bytes\nTotal transferred file size: 0 bytes\nLiteral data: 0 bytes\nMatched data: 0 bytes\nFile list size: 0\nFile list generation time: 0.001 seconds\nFile list transfer time: 0.000 seconds\nTotal bytes sent: 5,247\nTotal bytes received: 1,916\n\nsent 5,247 bytes  received 1,916 bytes  2,865.20 bytes/sec\ntotal size is 0  speedup is 0.00\n"
```

I verified that this was working by copy pasting the entire content of the new file as the argument to the discord.sh embed description like this:

```sh
discord.sh --webhook-url=URL --description="THE CONTENT OF THE TEMP.JSON FILE PASTED IN HERE"
```

This produced the expected result:

[image]

**The Problem**

I cannot figure out how to pass the content of the converted log file as an argument to discord.sh. I verified the format of the file is correct with the straight copy paste but I cannot get it to read the content of the file in bash.

What I tried:

- `$(< /path/to/file)`
- `$(cat /path/to/file)`
- `´/path/to/file´`

I've exhausted all suggestions I could find online. It either returns an error for message containing invalid JSON or it treats every new word of the file content as a new argument and gives me an error about a word being an invalid argument. Even though the file clearly contains quotes and it should treat it as one string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think Bash removes the backslashes at some point in your code. I advise that you double check the contents of your variables each step as you try to pass it to the webhook bot.

I have a test.txt in my home dir:

`line1 bla bla bla\nline2 bla bla bla\nline3 bla bla bla\nline4 bla bla bla\nline5 last one`

then I read that file with cat (note that the file is one line as the end of line is replaced with \n)

`messagearray=($(cat test.txt))`

you can then pass this to your bot

`sendcontent='{"username": "Yui", "content": "'"${messagearray[@]}"'"}'`

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$sendcontent" "$webhookurl"`

This is tested and works with my bot.

I don't exactly know where your code went wrong, but I hope this helps if you try it the way I showed.